# delete records from multiple collections on the basis of value present in MainCollection (mongoose) Express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello everyone I'm new to mongo and i'm stuck on something. I'm creating a expense tracker using react.js express.js and mongodb.

I've 2 collections : TrancstionSchema

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    createdDate: Date,
    amount:Number,
    expenseType:String,
    category:String
})
```

Category Schema

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    createdDate: Date,
})
```

If user delete a Category it should remove it's records from Category schema and transactions schema

[image: Categorylist]

as you can see that Category List title is referenced to transactionList as a category

[image]

**

> If User delete a category it record should be deleted from both
> collections categoryList and transaction list .

** Please help with a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a middleware function to run automatically after your category schema `remove` operation:

```
// Category schema
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  createdDate: Date,
})

schema.post('remove', async (doc, next) => {
  // Delete all records from transaction schema with category
  await Transaction.deleteMany({ category: doc.title })
  // OR Update the category of transactions to empty string
  await Transaction.updateMany({ category: doc.title }, { category: '' })
  next()
})
```

Calling the `remove` function on a category document will automatically delete all transaction with the same category associated:

```
await category.remove();
```